# Loading table dynamically loses style rules

Tags: css, jquery, dynamic, load

I am loading a page with table in a generated div in jquery. The loading goes fine, but the table loses its styles. I have tried to apply styles on the loaded page, on the landing page, and even inline styles on the table. The inline style works partially, like background color, but text doesn't allow me to change font type, size, weight.

```
$('<div/>', {
       id: 'newdiv',
       }).appendTo('body');

$('#newdiv').load('combi/page.with.table.php');
```

The table is simplified. No styles on tr or td.

```
<table style="font-size:x-large; font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace; text-align:right; background:#0F0" width="800" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
    </table>
```

Comment: What styles do you have for `#newdiv`?

Comment: I wonder if the mixed quotes in the style is somehow causing an issue. What happens if you remove the font-family style from the table?

Comment: I found the culprit. I had overseen the correct naming of an id on a tag in the loaded table. O darn. Time to take a break here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a stylesheet to control the style of the table, make sure the stylesheet is in a path relative to the loaded page and not the page which is being loaded.

Comment: The script is fired from a loaded page to start with. I started to apply style rules scattered around the place. In the end I found the human spell error that I persistently overlooked.

Comment: I'd like to add that styles in the head section of the loaded page do work fine as well.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. And this solution doelsn't solve it. The relevant CSS is in a path relative to the host page. It is definitely in memory. But if I use `$("#some-selector").append(newNode);` or `$("#someselector").load("/path/to/newNode.html");` , the 'newNode' appended or loaded, does not take the styles that are already loaded... I find that I have to manually add the style like `$(".loadedElement").css('some-style','some-value')` ... Has anyone solved this?

Comment: @Nutritioustim - if you link the style-sheet and you work with a directory structure, the path should be relative to the page you load into. If you place the styles in the head section of the, you also have to take in mind that paths to images need to be relative to the hostpage.