# JQuery dynamically added DOM loses (doesn't) CSS style

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, load

I'm having a problem where in JQuery, dynamically added DOM nodes don't take styles defined in a CSS file.

I've looked around, and [the answers I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134451/loading-table-dynamically-loses-style-rules), don't fix the problem. Ie, the relevant CSS is in a path relative to the host page. It is definitely in memory. But if I use A) or B), the 'newNode' appended or loaded, does not take the styles that are already loaded.

A) `$("#some-selector").append(newNode);`

B) `$("#some-selector").load("/path/to/newNode.html");`

I find that I have to manually add the style like

C) `$(".loadedElement").css('some-style','some-value');`

Has anyone solved this?

Thanks in advance.

--- EDIT

So I got a bit further. I had an HTML like A) and CSS like B). It turns out that the nested CSS selector wasn't matching the nodes I wanted. I had to go down to a selector as in C). Then my dynamic nodes have the style applied. But I really would prefer to have something like B). Is my CSS off?

A)

```
<div id='6bullet-container'>
  <input id='six-bullet-image-upload' name='convert' type='file'>
    <div class='six-bullet-content-wrapper'>
      <div class='six-bullet-container-label'>
        click to upload
      </div>
      <div id='six-bullet-title'></div>
      <div class='six-bullet-bullet' id='six-bullet-one'></div>
      <div class='six-bullet-bullet' id='six-bullet-two'></div>
      <div class='six-bullet-bullet' id='six-bullet-three'></div>
      <div class='six-bullet-bullet' id='six-bullet-four'></div>
      <div class='six-bullet-bullet' id='six-bullet-five'></div>
      <div class='six-bullet-bullet' id='six-bullet-six'></div>
   …
```

B)

```
#6bullet-container #six-bullet-image-upload .six-bullet-content-wrapper .six-bullet-bullet {
   my: style;
}
```

C)

```
.six-bullet-bullet {
    my: style;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter how elements end up in the DOM, they'll have the same styles applied. There's some issue with your new elements matching your CSS selectors, but since you've provided neither the elements, nor the CSS, I can't help you. I assume you've confirmed that elements coded directly into the HTML get the proper styles?

Comment: @amnotiam is right about the CSS selector; it may also be that by the time you get your html into the $("#some-selector") the styles are not defined corectly, better check $("#some-selector").load("/path/to/newNode.html",function(data){console.log(data)}); to see exactly what you get from server

Comment: Can you show us your css just in case?

Comment: Yes, you were right about  an issue with my new elements matching your CSS selectors. See the CSS in the EDIT abouve. That should work, no?

Answer (score 2):

This CSS selector:

```
#6bullet-container #six-bullet-image-upload .six-bullet-content-wrapper .six-bullet-bullet  { ... }
```

Implies that "six-bullet-content-wrapper" is a child of "six-bullet-image-upload" which is impossible because "six-bullet-image-upload" is a file input box and cannot have children.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. And since the rendered HTML reflects what  you said, I had tried `#6bullet-container .six-bullet-content-wrapper .six-bullet-bullet` to cut out that node from the CSS selector. But that didn't work. What I ended up doing was starting my selector from the point just below the text input: `.six-bullet-content-wrapper .six-bullet-bullet`. ... And that works. You are absolutely correct in your analysis though. Thanks.